# gltf2.0 issue after export

Tags: export

I am  trying to export a scene to gltf format, and load it with threejs gltf2loader. However after I the export the edges are more visible, I'm not sure if it is the exporter issue or I must do something to my scene in Blener. I do not see this problem when I render my scene with cycles

Do somebody have this issue before?

this is how my material looks like

[image]

myexporting settings are the following:

[image]

Comment: When you say "the edges are more visible" what do you mean? Can you share before/after screenshots and ideally the `.blend` file? Are you using smoothing? Perhaps see [this issue](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/issues/122).

Comment: Hi, thank you for you replay. The problem was the normals, I have forgotten  to recalculate them. This made my object look less  smooth.

Comment: Ok, glad you figured it out. Could you post that as an answer to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching in blender manual I find out that the problem was the shading mode. Basically edge was clearly visible because I applied flat shading to my model and then exported it.

The changes I made to my gltf exporter didn't affect my model at all.

[image]

to change you can change shading mode in transform tab in object mode

[image]